# Unexpected behavior when attempting to write a UMID using the -write_bext option with FFmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

I previously asked this question in relation to a Swift function, but it appears that the issue persists even when using the pure FFmpeg CLI.

My goal is to write the following UMID to a WAV file:

> 0x68753A444D6F12269C600050E4C0006773F8EDBBEA4680008E310CEB.

However, when I subsequently read the file from output.wav, the UMID is displayed as:

> 0x68753A444D6F12267FFFFFFFFFFFFFFF73F8EDBBEA4680007FFFFFFFFFFFFFFF

Here is the command I am using:

```
-i input.wav -c copy -write_bext 1 -metadata umid="0x68753A444D6F12269C600050E4C0006773F8EDBBEA4680008E310CEBB2D3F938" output.wav
```

Am I overlooking something, or is this behavior a malfunction?

Answer (score 0):

Each 16-digit hex portion of the 64-digit UMID is converted to a long long and then stored. If a 16-digit hex portion is out of range for a long long type then LLONG_MAX or LLONG_MIN is written. That's what has happened with the 2nd and 4th portion.

Comment: Thank you Gyan.
Is this a limitation of FFmpeg, because the UMID I was trying to write was retrieved from a wav file, created with AVID Pro Tools.
How could I work around it?

Comment: Can you share that WAV file?

Comment: Ok, identified the ffmpeg bug. Should be patched soon.

Comment: Good to hear. How can I share the wav?

Comment: Not needed now.